# Qualtrics Sum Matrix Table

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm trying to recreate the matrix in Qualtrics from this image:

[image]

The Javascript I found uses *text entry* but I think ***profile multiple answer*** would be better suited for this question.  I need a way to allow users to select multiple items and display their current total.  My sincere thanks to anyone that can point me in the right direction.

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var qid = this.questionId;
    $(qid).select('td.c4').last().down().hide();
    $(qid).select('td.c5').last().down().hide();
    var totalInput = $(qid).select('td.c6').last().down();
    totalInput.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    totalInput.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    var c6 = $(qid).select('td.c6');
    for(var i=0; i < (c6.length - 1); i++) {
        c6[i].down().observe("keyup", function(event) {
            sumCol();
        }); 
    }   
    sumCol();   

    function sumCol() {
        var total = 0;
        for(var i=0; i < (c6.length - 1); i++) {
            var inputValue = parseInt(c6[i].down().value);
            if(isNaN(inputValue)) inputValue = 0;
            c6[i].down().value = inputValue;
            total = total + inputValue;
        }
        totalInput.value = total;
        if(total == 100) totalInput.style.color = "";
        else totalInput.style.color = "red";
    }   
});
```

Comment: Hey, that's my code you posted (from github gist).  It is meant for an entirely different purpose...to have a constant sum on a single matrix column.  The picture you posted isn't really a matrix.  It is a multiple choice, multiple answer question in a 4 column format.  The sum would have to be in a different question. The  script to achieve what you are trying to do would be completely different.  Sorry...I currently don't have time to figure it out.

Comment: Hey T. Gibbons!!  You're the person I was hoping would respond.  Thank you for your response.  I will try to modify your code for my purposes using multiple choice multiple answer.  If you know anyone else that could offer some advice, could you pass this post on to them?  Thank you for your time and response!